# jquery align progress bar

Tags: jquery, html, progress-bar, alignment

this is my situation:

**HTML**

```
<p>Controlla mail</p>
<div class="progressbar"></div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".progressbar").progressbar({ value: 10 });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/michelejs/SByqS/

How can I align the progress bar with check mail text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here: [DEMO JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Zmy6/)

Or with jQuery only:

### [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/4Zmy6/2/)

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".progressbar").progressbar({
        value: 10
    }).css({marginLeft:'100px'}).prev('p').css({float:'left', lineHeight:'34px'});

});
```

Comment: Added a jQuery solution, if you like it more this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try  http://jsfiddle.net/mraufk/4K8X2/1/

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".progressbar").progressbar({ value: 10 });
    $(".progressbar").css('width', '85px'); 
});
```

Comment: @michele: Did you mean this by using the word 'align' ?

Comment: no sorry, i would that check mail and the progress bar appair in the same line. no new line

Comment: @michele Could you please post an image (you may use an image editor, like Microsoft Paint).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

> jQuery(function($) {
>
> $(".progressbar").progressbar({ value: 10 });
>
> $(".progressbar").css('margin-left', '90px');
>
> $('p').css('float','left');
>
> });