# jquery progress bar alignment problem

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, alignment

I am not be able to align the text "controlla mail" with the progressbar on this page:
http://mongolera.dyndns.biz/projects/gestionalePreventivi/

I followed this guide but it don't work.
[jquery align progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759183/jquery-align-progress-bar/6759857#6759857)
Can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: I want this result: http://jsfiddle.net/michelejs/GepXJ/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/B95ph/1/ here it work well...in css box i have copied all the css line in my project..but on mi link it is not working........this is very strange...what may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only "Controlla Mail" text?

Try

`<p class="alignprogressbar"`**`style="text-align:center;"`**`>Controlla mail</p>`

Comment: Ops, sorry. Misunderstanding.  `<p class="alignprogressbar">Controlla mail</p><div class="progressbar"></div>`  . Try wrapping the two elements with a DIV and set both _flot_ attribute to left.

Comment: As you can see it'is not working: http://localhost/projects/gestionalePreventivi/index.html

Comment: mmmm _localhost_ seems not available for me ... :-)

Comment: @michele let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1660/discussion-between-alesdario-and-michele)